# Structure-better structure or bishop pair in the endgame?

Tags: endgame, pawn-structure, doubled-pawn, bishop-pair

Does the bishop pair compensate for doubled pawns if there are no rooks to attack with the bishops in the endgame?

Comment: It depends.  Give us a sample position.  Many factors determine which side has the edge in an end game.

Comment: agree with edwina oliver here, an example position would be great.  Doubled pawns can be an advantage with rooks on if they help control key square on an open file and provide outposts for the bishops.

Comment: This question is exactly the type that I love to answer, but this is WAY too general. All other things being equal, the bishops are still better than worrying about one set of doubled pawns.

Comment: You could mention double pawn along which file. Generally, they should compensate. But, since the bishop pair works best in a somewhat open position, double pawns along central files are very likely to put the advantage of double bishops to minimum.

Comment: You may want to study examples from the Exchange Ruy Lopez after the queens are traded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More often than not, the Bishop pair will compensate for doubled pawns in an endgame.
Your unopposed bishop would have to be pretty bad (and therefore your overall position) if it's influence did not compensate.

In general doubled-pawns are not that bad if you have active piece play.  Look at the games from the Kasparov-Short world championship match.  Nigel Short repeatedly had doubled crappy looking pawns but because his pieces were active Kasparov was not able to capitalize on their weakness; this fact was well commented at the time.

Comment: Just clear my memory  about this please: would you give a pawn for the two bishops in most cases or would you give the pawn for the two bishops only if you had other strategic advantages, like doubled rooks on the open file?

Comment: @Marcelo To be clear we are talking about accepting doubled-pawns; not a pawn sacrifice.  So B+B vs N+B.  Adding more active rooks to the two bishops is not required for compensation and would certainly make such compensation obvious if not an advantage.

Comment: yes, I just wanted to ask that other question here instead of creating another thread...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the position, but a bishop is generally considered strong of play is on both sides of the boards and it's an open board. I would think that a sample position would help to understand what are you trying to point out.

Comment: that added nothing from the comments above.